# Permission has an unresolved reference to object

Tags: sql-server, azure, export

I am trying to make a BACPAC of my db.  When I do I get a series of errors "Error SQL71501: Error validating element Permission: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[Accounts]."  The twist to this is the tables with which it has issues are all External Tables.

I have tried excluding the external tables but that doesn't seem to affect the permission issue.  I had hoped there was a way to find and exclude the permission but I have yet to discover it.

So far the answers I've found here and elsewhere do not address this particular scenario.  I am hopeful someone here has run across this issue and has advice for me.

Comment: Hi George,  did the error solved now?

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and haven't found some one has the same error with you.

You should login with ServerAdmin and try again.

I have an another idea that  you can run the [Data Migration Assistant(DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017) to assistant your database before export or migration.

To run an assessment, you have to be a member of the SQL Server **sysadmin** role.

If there are no error after database assistant, try to export or migrate again.

Hope this helps.